# Schema Validator "nillable" For Child Nodes Doesn't Work?

Tags: .net, validation, xsd

For some reason I can't quite get **nillable** to work correctly with the .Net schema validator.  I'm trying to find a way to make a parent node optional but at the same time prevent an empty node from passing through the validator.

Here's the current element validator:

```
    <xs:element name="Dates" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="From" type="datetime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
          <xs:element name="To" type="datetime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

I've tried changing the **Dates** element to **nillable="false"** but that doesn't work -- an empty node still makes it past the validator.

I've also tried changing all three element nodes to **nillable="false"** -- which works fine for detecting an empty parent node but results in both children becoming required nodes instead of remaining optional.

So am I missing something here?  Yes, I can always just throw some code at it and make it work... but I'm betting that there's a variation here in the schema declarations that will give me what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in your case is "multiple choice":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Dates" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2">
                            <xs:choice maxOccurs="1">
                                <xs:element name="From" type="xs:dateTime" />
                            </xs:choice>
                            <xs:choice maxOccurs="1">
                                <xs:element name="To" type="xs:dateTime" />
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:choice>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**valid documents**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <Dates>
        <From>2010-01-20T12:34:45</From>
        <To>2011-01-20T12:34:45</To>
    </Dates>
</root>


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <Dates>
        <From>2010-01-20T12:34:45</From>
    </Dates>
</root>


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <Dates>
        <To>2011-01-20T12:34:45</To>
    </Dates>
</root>
```

**invalid document**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <Dates/>
</root>
```

---

**The simple way**

```
<xs:element name="Dates" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2" processContents="lax" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Where your only way of enforcing `<From />` and `<To />` would be using a special namespace.

Comment: Very close, I think, but your first example (with From/To nodes) fails validation (see http://www.xmlforasp.net/SchemaValidator.aspx).  This looks like its heading in the right direction, but when I fiddled with your schema on the schema validatator site I just made things worse. :-)

Comment: @jerhewet You're right indeed. My version posted is missing the `maxOccurs="2"` for the outer `choice`.

Comment: You *are* Da Man!  Or maybe Da Woman -- but in either case / gender this is KAZACTLY what I was looking for!  Very happy camper!